# Importing a Keras Python CNN to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, import, keras, conv-neural-network

Is there a possibility I can import a CNN, that was implemented using Python and Keras, and use it in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting version 2014b, Matlab allows to call python libraries without import. For example:

```
py.os.getcwd
```

If your python is not installed at typical path, you may need to, for the first time, set up python version by

```
pyversion('myPythonFolder/python.exe')
```

For more information and limitation, you can read [matlab doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

using Matlab 2017b you can import keras models with the add-on importKerasNetwork. For example, to load keras' vgg16 you can

```
netk=importKerasNetwork('vgg16.h5','OutputLayerType','classification');
```

I did not use keras' file but had to load it to keras and save it because of some missing metadata. on python terminal I did:

```
from keras import applications
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=True,weights='imagenet')
model.save('vgg16.h5')
```

Comment: How did you handle the `Unable to import network. Weight sharing is not yet supported.` problem.